# How to test Bootstrap HTML to find all of deprecated/obsolete tags?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, web-testing, html-rendering

For example, I found the legacy HTML code with `<span class="label label-important"> X </span>`. It's just doesn't render (`X` is invisible) because `label label-important` is obsolete in the new version of Bootstrap. I have rewritten it as `label label-warning` and it's working fine now - but this is just one place where an old Bootstrap class exists in a big project.

How to **test** Bootstrap HTML in a big project to find **all of the deprecated/obsolete tags**?

Answer (score 0):

I'll update this answer if I find a solution for that but as of right now you can't expect any automated solutions for that because just the current Bootstrap 4 version (beta 3) that was released about 2 weeks ago has introduced a few breaking changes as compared to the previous beta version.

Now, the next Bootstrap 4 version will be the final release and it won't introduce any breaking changes anymore. But as I said, at the moment, your chances to find an automated solution are close to zero.

Also, it's not just that some "tags" have become obsolete. There's a bit more involved when doing a full conversion.

Comment: Just yesterday they released Bootstrap 4.0.0. final.

Comment: And how about testing ?

Comment: By "testing" you actually mean migration from Bootstrap 3 to Bootstrap 4, right? As I said earlier, you won't get away with just "testing". It's a bit more complex to migrate from version 3 to version 4.

Comment: And the reason why it's complex is: They didn't just "replace a few tags" as you seem to imply. The entire damn thing was completely rewritten. COMPLETELY. A few bits and pieces remain similar but not very much. OK, I might be exaggerating by saying it was "completely" rewritten but that is closer to the truth than you might think.

Comment: What can be easily done is converting the basic grids. That's easy. But as soon as it gets beyond the mere basics, things start getting quite complex. There's no one-to-one conversion possible in many cases. So, even automated tools won't be able to automate everything. You're still gonna have to do manual touch-ups.

Comment: Wikipedia says it's "almost" a complete rewrite: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap_(front-end_framework)#Bootstrap_4 So, I wasn't too far off after all. Lot's of things are done very differently compared to Bootstrap 3. So, no conversion tool will be able to automate it all. Only basic parts.